# Show that $a_n = \frac{n}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{n^3}$ is a Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I want to show that

$$a_n = \frac{n}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{n^3}$$

is a Cauchy sequence.

My attempt:

$$|a_m-a_n|=|(\frac{m}{2m+1}-\frac{n}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{m^3}-\frac{1}{n^3})|$$
$$\leq\frac{m}{2m+1}+\frac{n}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{m^3}+\frac{1}{n^3}$$
$$<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{N^3}+\frac{1}{N^3}$$
$$=1+\frac{2}{N^3}$$
$$\leq \epsilon\Rightarrow N(\epsilon)\geq(\frac{2}{\epsilon-1})^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

But this seems a bit off?

Any thoughts?

Comment: That will never get $|a_m-a_n|<1$.

Comment: It converges to $1/2.$ So you're better off getting $m$ and $n$ so that $|a_m - 1/2 |$ and $|a_n - 1/2 |$  less than $\varepsilon/2,$ then use the triangle inequality.

Comment: I am aware that it converges to 1/2, but I want to show convergence without knowing its limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it wrong here:

$$\begin{align}|a_m - a_n| &= \left|\frac{m}{2m+1}-\frac{n}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{m^3}-\frac{1}{n^3}\right| \\
&\leqslant
\frac{m}{2m+1}+\frac{n}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{m^3}+\frac{1}{n^3}
\end{align}$$

I mean, it is *correct*, but it won't help. The number inside the absolute value bars is small precisely because of those subtractions, and expanding it the way you did makes those subtractions vanish.

You should try to keep the subtractions around:

$$\begin{align}|a_m - a_n| &= \left|\frac{m}{2m+1}-\frac{n}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{m^3}-\frac{1}{n^3}\right| \\
&\leqslant
\left|\frac{m}{2m+1}-\frac{n}{2n+1}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{m^3}-\frac{1}{n^3}\right|
\end{align}$$

Can you go on from here? [Hint: fix $m\leqslant n$. The other case, $n<m$, is similar.]

Answer (score 2):

You split too much, instead:

\begin{align}\left|\frac{m}{2m+1}-\frac{n}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{m^3}-\frac{1}{n^3}\right|
&\leq \left|\frac{m}{2m+1}-\frac{n}{2n+1}\right| + \left|\frac{1}{m^3}-\frac{1}{n^3}\right|\\
&\leq \left|\frac{m(2n+1) - n(2m+1)}{(2m+1)(2n+1)}\right| + \left|\frac{n^3-m^3}{m^3n^3}\right|\\
&= \frac{|m-n|}{(2m+1)(2n+1)} + \frac{|m-n||m^2+mn+n^2|}{m^3n^3}
\end{align}

I'll let you take it from here...